# How Can I add a div to the right of my responsive divs?

Tags: html, css

I basically want the label "div 1" to show on the right of the divs I have no matter what but to remain responsive. Is there a good way to do this?

I can't see to get a wrapper that still retains the responsiveness I want.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}
#second {
  background-color: blue;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.items .item {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #e0ddd5;
  color: #171e42;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 410px) {
  .items .item {
    max-width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 620px) {
  .items .item {
    max-width: calc(33.33333% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 830px) {
  .items .item {
    max-width: calc(25% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1040px) {
  .items .item {
    max-width: calc(20% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1250px) {
  .items .item {
    max-width: calc(16.66667% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1460px) {
  .items .item {
    max-width: calc(14.28571% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1670px) {
  .items .item {
    min-width: calc(12.5% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Bob</label>
        <br/>
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Bob</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Bob</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Bob</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Bob</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Bob</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
      DIV 1
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: On the right of the divs or in the last free position at the bottom right of the divs?

Comment: Is this kinda what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/a74qzy1y/ ?

Comment: I can break it down more and answer the question formally if it is.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Great. I'll answer then.

Comment: he align attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1: Float

Instead of using flexbox, consider using `display: inline-block` to order your divs. This has two advantages:

1) it has slightly better cross-browser support than flexbox (see: [caniuse on flexboxes](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)), in that IE10 and 11 don't 100% support it, and you may want to target those browsers

2) it allows us to take greater advantage of the `float` CSS property, which is useful for what you're looking for

If you make all of your `.item` divs `display: inline-block` and place your div that you want on the right next to them in the HTML, you can just apply a `float: right` to the right div, and it will work. This has a few caveats you should be aware of though, which I'll explain below.

#### HTML

*This is simplified from what you gave in your question*

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
        <br/>
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
        <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
      </div>

      <div class="right">
          DIV 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

#### CSS

```
.items .item{
    display: inline-block;
}

.items .right{
    float: right;
}
```

#### Known Issues

There are a few issues with this solution, but they are issues you may be ok with, especially if you know them ahead of time.

First off, if there are ever *no* items, you may need to clear the parent div so that it matches the floated element's height.

Second, similar to the first, if your right element is of a greater height that the total combined content of the items, you'll--again--need a clearfix for it.

---

### Solution 2: Side-by-Side Content

Another possible solution is to have all of your items contained in a div that is `x` width, and your right content to be contained in a div that is `y` width, where `y` is 100% of the screen width minus `x`.

#### HTML

So, let's take basically the same HTML (with some new wrappers):

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
                <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
                <br/>
                <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
                <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
                <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
                <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150324154025-14-internet-cats-restricted-super-169.jpeg" height="82" width="82" align="left">
                <label style="margin-top:1px;">Shane</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        DIV 1
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

In here, we just figure out how large we want the right content to be, then use the CSS `calc()` method to figure out the rest, and use the `float` property to keep them next to each other.

```
.left{
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.right{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

/* also throw in a clearfix for the wrapper */
.clearfix:after {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   font-size: 0;
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
}
```

And you'll get a very similar effect. The difference being that items that go beyond the height of the right content won't appear below it.

Note that in this case I used `150px` for the right content size, but you are free to change to to whatever you want, as long as you change it in the `calc()` and the right sizing.